# Rider freez with ASP.NET Core 2.1 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rider, jetbrains-rider

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application on Mac. When I am trying to build the application it freezes at the middle and nothing happens.

[image]

I can see the warning on the console

> The console output contains very long lines. Soft wraps were enable to improve performance

Comment: better off asking jetbrains

Answer (score 1):

Create a new issue in the JetBrains public issue tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Also attach IDE logs to this issue (Help -> Collect Logs).
The best thing you can do here is collect logs during IDE freeze. For that you have to

1. Run Rider and show logs in the Finder (Help -> Diagnostic Tools -> Show Log in Finder)
2. Reproduce the issue
3. Close \ Kill IDE
4. Zip all logs and attach to the issue (without restarting IDE!)